# How to select only 3 check boxes from my ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have created `ListView` with 10-15 list items each `ListView` item contain custom layout with one `CheckBox` in it.
What I want is that when I selected 3 `CheckBoxes` from `ListView` and trying to select 4th `CheckBox` from `ListView` then it should not be selected and tell user that you can not selected more than 3 `CheckBoxes` from `ListView`.

following is my getView() method
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

    view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
      final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr);
      viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

      view.setTag(viewHolder);
      viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(objects.get(position));
    } else {
      view = convertView;
      ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(objects.get(position));
    }
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.checkbox
    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
          boolean isChecked) {
        Model element = (Model) holder.checkbox
            .getTag();


        if(buttonView.isChecked())
        {
          count++;

          if(count >= 4)
              {
                 // element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                  element.setSelected(!buttonView.isChecked());
                  buttonView.setChecked(false);
                  Toast.makeText(ctx, "selected 3 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }  
          else {
              element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
              buttonView.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {

          if(count > 0)
          {
              count--;
          }

          element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
          buttonView.setChecked(false);
        }
        Log.e("count value", ""+count);

      }
    });
    holder.text.setText(objects.get(position).getName());
   // holder.checkbox.setChecked(objects.get(position).isSelected());
    return view;

}
```

Looking for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are maintaining the selected checkbox states?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you select a `CheckBox` keep a count and also simultaneously check the count when clicking the `CheckBox`. Now if the count is 2 (if starting from 0) disable the check.
`checkBox.setChecked(false);`

Comment: Please add your code to the post.  We want to see what you have tried so far. Please be clear as to what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in your Activity and override below method. Use static counter variable

```
private static int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (counter<3)
        counter++;
        else
        Toast.makeText(this,  "Only three please...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: you mean I need to write click action on listView

Comment: Yes. `yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Comment: But I don't want in that way.

Comment: yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(this) using this when u click on listView item checkBox get selected .

Comment: Add your custom listview code. Specially custom row layout.

Comment: I want checkBox get checked when click on it

Comment: I have added in question